# How to override Mezzanine comments form?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am using:

```
Python 2.7
Django 1.6.11
Mezzanine 3.1.10
```

Anyone who logins in my blog website can set the "name" field of the comments form for a blog post. I had the idea to hide this field but I can't find the template for the comment form.

Does anyone know where the comment form template is or another way to prevent users from setting the "name" field for comments?

Comment: Clean up english, removed "python-2.7" tag because it adds nothing the python tag adds and is mostly irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the templates by first copying the relevant template into your static/templates directory. Use the command

`./manage.py findstatic templates\something.html`

Ensure that your static files directory is set, then check that

`./manage.py findstatic templates\something.html`

finds both files, one from mezzanine and one from your static directory.

Example:

```
./manage.py findstatic css\bootstrap.css

Found 'css\bootstrap.css' here:
  C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\core\static\css\bootstrap.css
  c:\users\me\documents\mezz-project\mez\static\css\bootstrap.css
```